# Integral inequality $|\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx| \leq |\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx|$ with absolute values

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Let $f,g$ be continuous functions on the unit interval $[0,1]$. Further assume that $0\leq g(x)\leq 1$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx \neq 0$. Is it true that $$|\int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x) dx| \leq |\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx|?$$ This is true if $f$ is positive or if $g$ is a constant function. Also, if we allowed $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx =0$, the inequality doesn't necessarily hold as we can pick $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ and $g(x)=x$, that's why I assume the integral of $f$ is not zero.

If it still doesn't hold in general, what properties should be assumed on $f$ and $g$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx\geq0$. The inequality is not true if $f$ changes it's sign on $[0,1]$, i.e.
$$\left|\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right|<\int_0^1 |f(x)|dx.$$
If so, set $g(x)=I_{f\geq0}(x),$ then
$$\left|\int_0^1 f(x) g(x) d x\right| > \left|\int_0^1 f(x) d x\right|$$
Let $g_\epsilon=\rho_\epsilon * I_{f\geq0}(x)$, let $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, then you get your counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

if it is not true for $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = 0$, the chances that it becomes true when $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx \neq 0$ are very small. For example, take $\varepsilon > 0$, $f(x) = \varepsilon + \sin(2\pi x)$ and $g(x) = x$. It approches your counter-example when $\varepsilon \rightarrow 0$.

You can compute that $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x) \, dx = \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{1}{2\pi}$ and $\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx = \varepsilon > 0$. However, you don't have the wanted equality when $0 < \varepsilon < \frac{1}{\pi}$.